# Download files from server asp.net core 404 response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I'm trying to download a set of files from the server as zip file. Locally I can do it with no problem, but now that I deployed the app in a windows server 2019 (IIS), when I try to download the files I get the *404 - File or directory not found.*

To download the set of files as zip I'm using the **SharpZipLib** library. The file paths are all correct and I can access them thru the file system in the server.

First I'm uploading the files in a folder inside the *wwwroot* where I published the app. The structure of my folders inside *wwwroot* is:

- *wwwroot*

  - *docs*

    - *contracts*

My method to download the files as zip:

```
public async Task<FileResult> DownloadZipAsync() {
    List<string> filePaths = //linq query to get the file paths.
    //Example of file path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SRO\wwwroot\docs\contracts\testing.pdf

    var name = "contracts";

    var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    var fileName = name + ".zip";
    var tempOutput = webRoot + "\\docs\\contracts\\" + fileName;

    using (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(System.IO.File.Create(tempOutput))) {
        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(9);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        for (int index = 0; index < filePaths.Count; index++) {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(name + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filePaths[index]));
            entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
            entry.IsUnicodeText = true;
            zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

            using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePaths[index])) {
                int sourceBytes;
                do {
                    sourceBytes = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                } while (sourceBytes > 0);
            }
        }
        zipOutputStream.Finish();
        zipOutputStream.Flush();
        zipOutputStream.Close();
    }
    byte[] finalReuslt = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempOutput);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempOutput)) {
        System.IO.File.Delete(tempOutput);
    }
    if (finalReuslt == null && !finalReuslt.Any()) {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Nothing found"));
    }
    return File(finalReuslt, "application/zip", fileName);
```

}

Things I've tried to fix the issue:

1. In the server I gave my deployment folder permissions (full control) for *IIS_IUSRS* user
2. For my deployment folder I created the user *DefaultAppPool* and gave full permissions as well.
3. In IIS -> Application Pools -> myappPoolforNetCore -> Advanced Settings -> Identity - changed between ApplicationPoolIdentity and LocalSystem.

Maybe my download method is not working properly when deployed. I suspect the issue can be in the using statement, specifically in the *System.IO.File.Create()* method.

I 'deployed' the app on my local development machine thru *Development-time IIS support in Visual Studio for ASP.NET Core*. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I did the same three steps I mentioned above, and in this case it works, with one difference being that the paths of files are different (since my app is 'deployed' locally) and they point to my *C:/....* directory.

Any help would be appreciated because I'm stuck in this problem for quite a while.
Thanks

Comment: Where are the files located?  Ae you running IIS code as Admin?  A client connecting to a IIS has very little access to the IIS resources.  The client connection defaults to a GUEST.  So you should be using a network drive and has more access than the drives on IIS for the upload and download folder.

Comment: The files are inside the published folder in the server, inside wwwroot/docs/contracts. Do you have any pointers for the usage of network drive with more access.

Comment: If you do not have a network file server (which most companies with IIS would have) then make sure the folder in IIS is accessible to GUEST so the files can be downloaded by users.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the MIME Types ?

[image: MIME Types]

Try to add

> .zip - application/zip

or

> .zip - application/x-zip

Comment: Yes I checked, there's one type for zip file.